# How to change original value of outputtext

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a datatable in JSF that has an invoice total in the footer. I used a method to calculate the total on page load and that works fine. Each row in the datatable has a check box. When the user checks or unchecks the check box the page should recalculate the total by subtracting the cost for that row if the check box is unchecked or adding the cost to the total if it is checked. I've tried adding another outputtext to hold the new total and changing the value in the same outputtext. The problem is the new total is not getting rendered to the outputtext.

I have a static variable to hold the total as it changes. I've also tried using a method.

```
private static BigDecimal saveInvoiceTotal;
```

InvoiceTotal method in bean

```
public BigDecimal invoiceTotal() throws Exception {
            List<OrderDetail> selected = getDetails();
    BigDecimal invoiceTotal = new BigDecimal(0);

    for(OrderDetail d : selected) {         
        if(d.isSelected()) 
            invoiceTotal = invoiceTotal.add(d.getExtCost());
        else
            invoiceTotal = invoiceTotal.subtract(d.getExtCost());           
    }       

    saveInvoiceTotal = invoiceTotal;    

    return invoiceTotal;
}
```

This method is used to return the new total to the page.

```
public BigDecimal invoiceSelectedTotal() throws Exception {     

    return saveInvoiceTotal;
}
```

This method adds or subtracts the cost depending on if the check box is checked or unchecked

```
public void selectedRow(OrderDetail d) throws Exception {           

    if(d.isSelected())
        saveInvoiceTotal = saveInvoiceTotal.add(d.getExtCost());            
    else
        saveInvoiceTotal = saveInvoiceTotal.subtract(d.getExtCost());       

}
```

The datable

```
on page load <rich:dataTable id="detailTable" var="_detail" value="#{orderDetails.details}" rendered="#{not empty orderDetails.details}" style="width : 100%">                 
               <rich:column id="detail_itemnumber">
                  <f:facet name="header">Item Number</f:facet>
                  #{_detail.itemNumber}
                  <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:outputText value="Invoiced Total: " />
                    <h:outputText id="invTotal" value="#{orderDetails.invoiceTotal()}" rendered="#{_detail.invoiceRender}"/>
                    <h:outputText id="invSelectedTotal" value="#{orderDetails.invoiceSelectedTotal()}" rendered="#{not _detail.invoiceRender}"/>                        
                </f:facet>
               </rich:column>                                      
               <rich:column id="detail_extcost">
                  <f:facet name="header">Ext Cost</f:facet>
                  #{_detail.extCost}
                  <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:outputText value="Order Total: " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{orderDetails.orderTotal()}" />                       
                </f:facet>
               </rich:column>
               <rich:column id="detail_selected">
                  <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
                  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{_detail.selected}" >                        
                    <f:param name="orderNo" value="#{order.id}"></f:param>
                    <a4j:ajax listener="#{orderDetailController.selectedRow(_detail)}" /> 
                  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                     

               </rich:column>                   

            </rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Ajax and recall the method every time when user checks/unckecs

Comment: Nice point. I've tried that. Using the method above selectedRow above I call invoiceSelectedTotal and return the new total but the page doesn't display the new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
The solution was to use <f:ajax render="invTotal"/>


<rich:panel header="Order Detail">             
          <h:form>
          <rich:dataTable value="#{data.details}" var="abc">
                  <rich:column id="detail_itemnumber">
                      <f:facet name="header">
                          <h:outputText value="Item Number"/>
                      </f:facet>
                      <h:outputText value="#{abc.itemNumber}"/>
                      <f:facet name="footer">
                    <h:outputText value="Invoiced Total: " />
                    <h:outputText id="invTotal" value="#{data.invoiceTotal()}" />
                    <!-- <h:outputText id="invSelectedTotal" value="#{abc.invoiceAmount}" rendered="#{not abc.invoiceRender}"/> -->                     
                    </f:facet>                  
                 </rich:column>
                 <rich:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Item Description"/>
                     </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{abc.itemDesc}" />
                 </rich:column>
                 <rich:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Order Qty"/>
                     </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{abc.orderQty}" />                        
                 </rich:column>
                 <rich:column id="detail_invoiceqty" style="width : 10%">
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Invoice Qty"/>
                     </f:facet>
                     <h:inputText value="#{abc.invoiceQty}" >                           
                        <f:ajax render="invTotal" />
                        <a4j:ajax listener="#{data.calculateExtCost()}" render="extCost"/>
                     </h:inputText>
                 </rich:column> 
                 <rich:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Item Cost"/>
                     </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{abc.itemCost}" />                       
                 </rich:column>
                 <rich:column id="detail_extcost">
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Ext Cost"/>
                     </f:facet>
                  <h:outputText id="extCost" value="#{abc.extCost}" />
                     <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText value="Order Total: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.orderTotal()}" />                       
                     </f:facet>
                </rich:column>
                 <rich:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">
                         <h:outputText value="Selected"/>
                     </f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{abc.selected}" >
                            <!-- <a4j:ajax listener="#{data.invoiceTotal()}" /> -->
                            <f:ajax render="invTotal"/>                             
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>                      
                 </rich:column>                   
          </rich:dataTable>

public BigDecimal invoiceTotal() throws Exception {         
    List<OrderDetail> selected = getDetails();      
    BigDecimal newInvoiceTotal = new BigDecimal(0);                 

    for(OrderDetail d : selected) {         

        if(d.isSelected()) 
            newInvoiceTotal = newInvoiceTotal.add(d.getExtCost());                      
    }       

    return newInvoiceTotal;
}
```